# Rails has_many belongs_to with foreign_key and class_name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreign-keys, rails-activerecord, has-many, belongs-to

I'm trying to model a system of `User`s and `Message`s. `Message`s have `addresser`s and `addressee`s. `User`s have `sent_message`s and `received_messages`.

Right now the tests are failing as it can't seem to find addressee_id and addresser_id. I'd like to know if I have modeled this correctly and how I should go about creating messages through users.

Edit: The output from the tests

ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError:unknown attribute: addressee_id

Pops up in the before statement in the message spec.

User Model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sent_messages, class_name: "Message", foreign_key: "addresser_id"
  has_many :received_messages, class_name: "Message", foreign_key: "addressee_id"
```

Message Model

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :addresser_id, presence: true
  validates :addressee_id, presence: true
  belongs_to :addresser, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "addresser_id"
  belongs_to :addressee, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "addressee_id"
end
```

Migration

```
class CreateMessages < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :messages do |t|
      t.string :content     
      t.integer :addresser_id
      t.integer :addressee_id
      t.timestamps
    end
  add_index :messages, [:addressee_id, :addresser_id, :created_at]
  end
end
```

schema

```
create_table "messages", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "content"
    t.integer  "addresser"
    t.integer  "addressee"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "messages", ["addressee", "addresser", "created_at"], name: "index_messages_on_addressee_and_addresser_and_created_at"
```

message_spec

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Message do
  let(:user1) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  let(:user2) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  before { @message = user1.sent_messages.build(content: "Lorem ipsum", addressee_id: user2.id) }

  subject { @message }

  it { should respond_to(:content) }
  it { should respond_to(:addresser_id) }
  it { should respond_to(:addressee_id) }
  its(:addresser) { should eq user1 }

  it { should be_valid }

  describe "when addresser is not present" do
    before { @message.addresser = nil }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe "when addressee is not present" do
    before { @message.addressee = nil }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end
end
```

Comment: What does "the tests are failing" mean? What does "it can't seem to find addressee_id and addresser_id" mean? Don't just give the tables, give the rest of the code, the input and output. PS FKs go do not belong in User.

Comment: I added the output to the question. As for the input, I can't think of anything else to include. I too thought it was strange that there would be FKs in User, but according to http://www.spacevatican.org/2008/5/6/creating-multiple-associations-with-the-same-table/ that's the solution. @philipxy

Comment: The added info helps. Eg the table declarations it has to be consistent with. (See answer.) Also: If it had compiled & run, input & output data. You didn't explain "failing" and "can't find" or give an error message so we didn't know what was being done to what when it "failed". (Somewhere between compilation and running.) Include *everything* relevant to a *minimal* example. [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing this:

```
describe Message do
  ...
  before { @message = user1.sent_messages.build(content: "Lorem ipsum", addressee_id: user2.id) }
  subject { @message }
  ...
end
```

With this:

```
describe Message do
  ...
  let(:message){ user1.sent_messages.build(content: "Lorem ipsup", addressee_id: user2.id) }
  subject { message }
  ...
end
```

Also check that migrations are run in test environment.

Edit:
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError means that a column is missing from the database. The migration seems ok, but schema and the output of Message.column_names does not.

Seems your addressee_id / addresser_id is actually named addressee / addresser in the database. Did you edit migration file after running db:migrate?

Try running rake db:migrate:redo STEP=1 (if this was not your last migration, change step)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately it's just changing the error to another one: NoMethodError: undefined method 'addresser=' for nil:NilClass

Comment: You also meed to change both occurrences of `before { @message.addresser = nil }` to `before { message.addresser = nil }` Does all tests fail? Does the model work in the console?

Comment: Right, totally forgot that part. I changed it, but now it's back to the same old ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError:unknown attribute: addressee_id. I've tried creating messages in the console. Interestingly enough, Message.create is giving me a NoMethodError: undefined method 'addresser_id'

Comment: Did you run migrations? `rake db:migrate`

Comment: Yeah I ran db:migrate and test:prepare.

Comment: Try changing the validations to `validates_presence_of :addresser_id` and `validates_presence_of :addressee_id`

Comment: What is the output when you run `Message.column_names` in the console?

Comment: `2.0.0-p481 :001 > Message.column_names
 => ["id", "content", "addresser", "addressee", "created_at", "updated_at"]` 
it seems like addressee_id and addresser_id are not being created?

Comment: ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError means that something is missing from the database column. The migration seems ok, but schema and the output of Message.column_names does not. Seems your addressee_id / addresser_id is actually named addressee / addresser in the database. Did you edit migration file after running db:migrate? Try running rake db:migrate:redo STEP=1 (if this was not your last migration, change step)

Comment: I redid the migration and Message.column_names is displaying `2.0.0-p481 :001 > Message.column_names
 => ["id", "content", "addresser_id", "addressee_id", "created_at", "updated_at"]` However, the same errors as before are still popping up, although I can create messages properly in the console. I'll keep tinkering. Thanks!

Comment: You probably need to do `rake db:test:prepare` to update test database as well.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to do it like this

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sent_messages, class_name: "Message", as: :addressor
  has_many :received_messages, class_name: "Message", as: :addressee
```

and

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :addressor, class_name: "User", foreign_key: :addressor_id
  belongs_to :addressee, class_name: "User", foreign_key: :addressee_id
```

Comment: Hmm, tried this but it doesn't recognize the class. Unknown key: class (ArgumentError)

Comment: Sorry, I edited my answer, should have been class_name not class.

Comment: Also, to get it working, you could just have the user have many messages, then use scopes or methods to pull messages where their id is either the addressor or addressee.

Comment: No more ArgumentError, but it's back to the original ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError:unknown attribute: addressee_id

Comment: that's a good idea, I think I might just go ahead and do that. These associations are too painful to deal with.